# Getting error in mysql connection in Python

Tags: python, mysql, database, connector

I am very new in Python as wel as in backend develpoment. I want to connect my python code with database so I installed mysql-connector-python using `C:\Users\CCU-012\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts>python -m pip install mysql-connector-python` but when I use `import mysql.connector` in my python code I am getting error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/CCU-012/PycharmProjects/array/demo_mysql_connection.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'`[image: this is the code and the error which I am getting]

Answer (score 0):

You've installed the module globally, but your project is using a virtualenv (as evident from the "Python 3.7 (array)" text in PyCharm's status bar).

Install the module within the virtualenv; the easiest way to do that through PyCharm is to open the Python Console (4th tab at the bottom there) and

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```